# how to make scheduled process in asp.net/C# with mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 application that has a function to send e-mail to user after subscribing the newsletter. Now i have a requirement to send e-mail to all those users whose are running 1 month ahead of expiry date of their subscription. In this case i need to implement a background process that will run every day at a specific time on the web server. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: There are several ways. The easiest way is probably to make a console application that does this, and then make a scheduled task that runs it once every day.

Comment: simply: you don't - write another application instead you can then schedule using windows-tasks

Comment: In addition to answer from Cris W - Scott Hanselman covered [a number of good libraries allowing you to easily run a task in the background in asp.net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Windows Service to make that work for you. 
You should follow this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You can store the date/time on the project `web.config/app.config` which when you want your service to be executed. When the service executes, you validate the time and call a generic function that will do what you want. Follow this example:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    YourServiceClass service;
    private Timer serviceTimer;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        service = new YourServiceClass();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(service.GetData); // You should add this function to your class. You have an example below

        string time = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SceduleTime"];    // Gets time from app.config like 12:50
        string[] timeS = time.Split(':');

        DateTime DateIni = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, Convert.ToInt32(timeS[0]), Convert.ToInt32(timeS[1]), 0);

        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - DateIni;
        if (diff.TotalSeconds < 0)
            diff = DateIni - DateTime.Now;
        else
            diff = DateIni.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now;

        // create timer and attach our method delegate to it
        serviceTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, service, diff, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        serviceTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And on your **YourServiceClass** class, you add this function:

```
public void GetData(object state){
    // Do something...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd create a separate dedicated Windows Service to periodically check for expiry, and then call the code to send the emails.

An alternative is to create a simple console application to run the task, and call it using the Windows Task Scheduler.

A less secure method is to use a ping service, to periodically hit a page with an obfuscated URL which processes the emails.

A slightly old, but relevant blog post, detailing the issues with recurrent background tasks in .net sites [can be read here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements, and whether you want this update to be truly independent on the server, in a web application or bundled with your app.

I recently found a great third party library for ASP.NET called [Hang Fire](http://hangfire.io/).

It looks like it can be as simple as:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Transparent!"), 
    Cron.Daily);
```

It supports:

- Delayed Jobs
- Recurring Tasks
- Automatic Retries
- And it has a nicely themed Management/Reporting interface

I'm planning to use it for some scheduled batch tasks I need to run on a CRM system. No experience with it yet, but it does seem to have some great features  and I think I've seen it recommended a few times around Stack Overflow!

There are a ton of different ways to approach what you want (Scheduled Task on the server is another off the top of my head). This is a nice little package that lets me bundle it with my web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) library. Your process should be independent from your web application since the web app will recycle from time to time based on the user traffic which will trigger Application_End event and will start once a new request is sent which will trigger Application_Start so you wont be able to manage correctly your schedule start and end.